# Create expandable commands

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use ZSH via Oh-my-zsh, and one neat feature I see is that the shell expands my commands when they are in backticks.

For example, `` `pwd` `` + <kbd>tab</kbd>, replaces `` `pwd` `` with my current path:

[image: https://infinit.io/_/DjmxTCK.gif]

I am wondering if there's a relatively easy way to do the same for some commands without having to use the backticks. I'd like to apply that to some aliases (or functions).

To be clear, I am not talking about expanding arguments to a command, but the command itself.

---

This is a truly amazing feature, but is not exactly what I was looking for. Unless I did something wrong, this expands my alias to what the alias was defined to, but not to what the result is. For example here:

[image]

I would like to see the result of that command instead of the full command.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want to just type any command, press some key and replace the typed command with its output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom zle widget for this and call it by key binding, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (identical with <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

```
expand-to-output () {
    BUFFER='$('$BUFFER')'
    CURSOR=0
    zle redisplay
    zle expand-word
}
zle -N expand-to-output
bindkey "^[^I" expand-to-output
```

Now, if you type any command followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the whole command will be replaced by its output, *if* the command could be run successfully. If the command cannot be successfully run, the typed command line will just be surrounded by `$(...)` but not expanded. If there were error messages, they should be printed above the edit buffer. This may not work reliably with multi-line prompts.

**Explanation:**

- `expand-to-output () {...}` defines the (new) `expand-to-output` function.
- `BUFFER` contains the current command line
- `BUFFER='$('$BUFFER')'` places `$(` before and `)` after the command line. `$(...)` is equivalent to `` `...` `` but it can be nested.
- `CURSOR` is the position of the cursor on the command line
- `CURSOR=0` places the cursor on the beginning of the (edited) command line, that is on `$`. Without moving the cursor there, it could happen that `zsh` tries to expand a word inside of `$(...)` instead of the whole process substitution.
- `zle redisplay` redisplays the edit buffer. This prevents display errors should the expanded command print something to *stderr*. (Note: there can be some issues with multi-line prompts)
- `zle expand-word` calls the `expand-word` widget, which is usually often called as part of Tab-completion.
- `zle -N expand-to-output` registers the function as widget of the same name.
- `bindkey "^[^I" expand-to-output` binds the `expand-to-output` widget to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: This is a truly amazing feature, but is not exactly what I was looking for. Unless I did something wrong, this expands my alias to what the alias was defined to, but not to what the result is. For example here: https://infinit.io/_/yHyTVZM.gif I would like to see the result of that command instead of the full command